# Como conectar meu código Python com um jogo ou um programa?

Tags: python

Olá!

Comecei a estudar Python e vi nele umas possibilidades de fazer alguns Hacks para jogos e gostei mais ainda da linguagem hahaha.
Eu tenho um código que por exemplo, pega uma String e converte ela em outra palavra, mas eu gostaria de fazer isso pegando algum Texto de um jogo ou algum nome de um item. Como eu faço isso ? Digo, como eu faço para conectar os meu códigos com as informações passadas no jogo ?

Colocando dois exemplos: um jogo que eu tenho salvo no meu computador, no caso, um game Desktop e um jogo online via Browser.

É possível ?

Obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Eu não sei exatamente mas você precisa fazer uma conexão com o servidor usando 'connectTCP' pra isso precisa do modulo twisted